# Angular Flex Layout row wrap with grid align not working

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I've Angular `v13` application with `@angular/flex-layout` also `v13`. The issue is Flex layout of type `row wrap` with Grid alignment is not working as expected. Below is the `html` code block. The application is hosted in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-75dutd?file=src/app/app.component.html). If I remove the `grid` from `fxLayoutGap`, the layout is getting rendered without `gutter space` for second/subsequent rows.

```html
<div class="cards-container" style="width: 100%; syntax: 100%;">
  <div
    fxLayout="row wrap"
    fxLayoutAlign="start start"
    fxLayoutGap="32px 12px grid"
  >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of cards">
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{ item }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>subtitle</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img
          mat-card-image
          height="240px"
          width="240px"
          src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg"
          alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu"
        />
        <mat-card-content> </mat-card-content>
        <mat-divider inset></mat-divider>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>Ok</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
        <mat-card-footer>
          <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
        </mat-card-footer>
      </mat-card>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to configure `@angular/flex-layout` row wrap with grid?

**EDIT**

[image: Expected output]

Comment: So you want the layout to be rendered without `gutter space`? Just a bit confused as to the desired output while having `flex` and wanting `grid` on the same parent element.

Comment: @カメロン Edited with expected output grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, updated code can be accessed at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4tsya?file=src/app/app.component.html). Basically we need to wrap a div around `mat-card` and add `fxFlex` with percentage. In my case I had set it to 25 so that 4 cards come in first raw.

```
<div class="cards-container" style="width: 100%; syntax: 100%;">
  <div
    fxLayout="row wrap"
    fxLayoutAlign="start start"
    fxLayoutGap="32px 12px grid"
  >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of cards">
    <div fxFlex="25">  
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{ item }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>subtitle</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img
          mat-card-image
          height="240px"
          width="240px"
          src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg"
          alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu"
        />
        <mat-card-content> </mat-card-content>
        <mat-divider inset></mat-divider>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>Ok</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
        <mat-card-footer>
          <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
        </mat-card-footer>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```